# How to always merge with two parents?

Tags: git

My group will start using Git soon and would like to maintain a concise history on master. I would like to start breaking up big changes into lots of smaller changes but they don't want to see that on the master branch. My thought is to confine my little changes to a topic branch and then merge with master but the problem is if my topic branch is based on HEAD then the merge will simply result in a fast forward, rather than a new commit with two parents. How can I encourage Git to always create a new commit with multiple parents? I looked at --squash and disabling --ff but didn't have much luck but maybe I'm misunderstanding the behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git merge --no-ff
```

will always create a new merge commit, even if the merge is fast-forwardable.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Strange that it's not shown in the short help. Now how do I push the changesets from the branch to another server? Do I need to push the topic branch too?

Comment: @balor123 If I understand your question correctly, no, you don't necessarily need to push the topic branch if the commits you want to push are included in the history for the main branch you're pushing.  (And you don't care to publish the topic branch.)